# Can you FaceTime over 3G with jailbroken iPhone 4?

Tags: jailbreak, iphone, facetime

Can you FaceTime over 3G with jailbroken iPhone 4?

If so, can you FaceTime in following situations?

1. A initiates FaceTime over 3G with jailbroken iPhone 4. B is also on 3G with jailbroken iPhone 4.
2. A initiates FaceTime over 3G with jailbroken iPhone 4. B is also on 3G with non-jailbroken iPhone 4.
3. A initiates FaceTime over wifi connection. B is on 3G with jailbroken iPhone 4.
4. A initiates FaceTime over wifi connection. B is on 3G with non-jailbroken iPhone 4.

Comment: Can you voice call someone using 3G on one of over a thousands calls, to anyone else on 3G using one of over a thousand phones?  Yes.  Did anyone ever do it? No. Do most new phones not bother with the camera on the front now? Yes.  `</rant>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes to all of your questions.

The Jailbreak app `My3G` tricks your iPhone into thinking it is on WiFi, enabling you to use FaceTime over 3G.

Source: http://www.macrumors.com/2010/08/02/facetime-over-3g-comes-to-jailbroken-iphone-4s/

Comment: Ah.. that's great.

Comment: should be noted that a Facetime call uses approx. 3MB/minute of 3G data.

Answer (score 1):

Just to update an old question, this is now a carrier issue - most carriers either allow Facetime over cellular or have an option to pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

[3G Unrestrictor](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.crashx.unrestrictor3g) does this as well, and it's available in Cydia, so you don't have to put Rock on your phone.